# How can I use elements added with appendChild() in forEach function?

Tags: javascript

So I have a website displaying movies from movie API, there're about 20 items on one page, so when I click on a movie I want to display a div with the movie's description and stuff. Example:
https://entertainmenthub.netlify.app/
As you see, when you click on a movie it display a div with its description.
So I'm trying to do the same:

```
//importing elements
    const movie = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target');
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    const close = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
```

Function for displaying movies:

```
trendingMovies = movies =>{
        movie_container.innerHTML = '';

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            img = IMG_URL + movie.poster_path;
            title = movie.title;
            rate = movie.vote_average;
            date = movie.release_date;
            tagline = movie.original_language;

            const movieEl = document.createElement('div');
            movieEl.classList.add('movie');
            movieEl.setAttribute("data-modal-target", ".popup");

            movieEl.innerHTML = 
            `<span class="rate">${rate}</span>
            <img src="${img}">
            <span class="movie_title">${title}</span>
            <span class="movie_date" style="text-align: left;">${tagline}</span>
            <span class="movie_date">${date}</span>
                `
            movie_container.appendChild(movieEl);

        });
```

Function for adding popup to movie_container:

```
function popUp(){
        const popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.classList.add('popup');
        popup.innerHTML = 
        `<div class="popup_left">
        <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="popup_right">
            <span class="text" id="popup_title">Movie Title</span>
            <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">Tagline</span>
            <div class="description">
            </div>
        </div>
    <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        `;
    movie_container.appendChild(popup);
    
        movie.forEach(el =>{
            el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
                const modal = document.querySelector(el.dataset.modalTarget)
                openModal(modal);
            })
        })
```

Function for opening popup:

```
function openModal(modal){
            if(modal == null) return
            modal.classList.add('active');
            overlay.classList.add('active');
        }
    }
```

So as you see, in trendingMovies() function it gets movies from API and displays them on the page in divs, and then, in popup function I want to add popup element to movie_container, which isn't active, so it shouldn't display.
And when I click on any of the movies, this popup should be displayed, but it doesn't happen, I imported all elements with 'data-modal-target' like this:

```
const movie = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target');
```

And make forEach function for each movie inside of popUp function, but when I click on any movies nothing does happen, and popUp function doesn't work for some reason, because popup element isn't added in the movie container.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    const API_KEY = 'api_key=73b31f15b44a93f52789c751c34a5d7d';
    const BASE_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
    const API_URL = '/discover/movie?' + API_KEY + '&sort_by=popularity.desc';
    const IMG_URL = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';

    const url = BASE_URL + API_URL;
    const movie_container = document.getElementById('movie_container');
    const prev = document.getElementById('prev');
    const next = document.getElementById('next');
    const numbs = document.querySelectorAll('.numb');
    const genres = document.querySelectorAll('.genre');
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    const close = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
    const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

    var lastUrl = '';
    var currentPage = 1;
    var nextPage = 2;
    var prevPage = 3;
    var totalPages = 100;


    fetchURL(url);


    function fetchURL(url){
        lastUrl = url;
        fetch(url)
        .then(console.log(url))
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>{
            trendingMovies(data.results);
            currentPage = data.page;
            nextPage = currentPage + 1;
            prevPage = currentPage - 1;
            totalPages = data.total_pages;
            lastPage = totalPages;
            
            if(currentPage <= 1){
                prev.classList.add('disabled');
                next.classList.remove('disabled');
            }
            else if(currentPage >= lastPage){
                prev.classList.remove('disabled');
                next.classList.add('disabled');
            }else{
                prev.classList.remove('disabled');
                next.classList.remove('disabled');
            }
        })
    }   

    trendingMovies = movies =>{
        movie_container.innerHTML = '';

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            img = IMG_URL + movie.poster_path;
            title = movie.title;
            rate = movie.vote_average;
            date = movie.release_date;
            tagline = movie.original_language;

            const movieEl = document.createElement('div');
            movieEl.classList.add('movie');
            movieEl.setAttribute("data-modal-target", ".popup");

            movieEl.innerHTML = 
            `<span class="rate">${rate}</span>
            <img src="${img}">
            <span class="movie_title">${title}</span>
            <span class="movie_date" style="text-align: left;">${tagline}</span>
            <span class="movie_date">${date}</span>
                `
            movie_container.appendChild(movieEl);


        });
        
    }; 
    popUp(); 

    function popUp(){
        let movief = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
        const popup = document.createElement('div');
        popup.classList.add('popup');
        popup.innerHTML = 
        `<div class="popup_left">
        <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="popup_right">
            <span class="text" id="popup_title">Movie Title</span>
            <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">Tagline</span>
            <div class="description">
            </div>
        </div>
    <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        `;
    movie_container.appendChild(popup);
    
    console.log(movief);
    
        movief.forEach(el =>{
            el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
                const modal = document.querySelector(el.dataset.modalTarget)
                openModal(modal);
            })
        })
    
        function openModal(modal){
            if(modal == null) return
            modal.classList.add('active');
            overlay.classList.add('active');
        }
    }

    prev.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
            if(prevPage > 0){
                pageCall(prevPage);
            }
            let numb = document.querySelectorAll('.numb.active');
            numb.forEach(el =>{
                if(el.classList.contains('active')){
                    el.classList.remove('active');
                }
            })
    
            let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
                li.forEach(element =>{
                    if(element.innerText == prevPage){
                        element.classList.toggle('active');
                    }
                })
        })

    next.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        if(nextPage <= totalPages){
            pageCall(nextPage);
        } 
        let numb = document.querySelectorAll('.numb.active');
        numb.forEach(el =>{
            if(el.classList.contains('active')){
                el.classList.remove('active');
            }
        })
        let li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
            li.forEach(element =>{
                if(element.innerText == nextPage){
                    element.classList.toggle('active');
                }
            })
    })

     function pageCall(page){
      let url = new URL(lastUrl)
      url.searchParams.set("page", page)      
      fetchURL(url);
      console.log(typeof(page));
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        } 

    numbs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
        if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            e.target.classList.remove('active');
          } else if (!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            let numb = document.querySelectorAll('.numb.active');
            numb.forEach(num =>{
                if(num.classList.contains('active')){
                    num.classList.remove('active');
                }
            })
            e.target.classList.toggle('active');
          }
            pagination(e);
            }));


    genres.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            e.target.classList.remove('active');
          } else if (!e.target.classList.contains('active')) {
            e.target.classList.toggle('active');
          }
          genreChoose(e);    
    }))

    function genreChoose(e){
        let genres = {
            'Action': '28',
            'Adventure': '12',
            'Animation': '16',
            'Comedy': '35',
            'Crime': '80',
            'Documentary': '99',
            'Drama': '18',
            'Family': '10751',
            'Fantasy': '14',
            'History': '36',
            'Horror': '27',
            'Music': '10402',
            'Mystery': '9648',
            'Romance': '10749',
            'Science_Fiction': '878',
            'TV_Movie': '10770',
            'Thriller': '53',
            'War': '10752',
            'Western': '37'
        };
        params = new URLSearchParams('');
        document.querySelectorAll('.genre.active').forEach(f => params.append('with_genres', genres[f.innerText]));
        console.log(params.toString());
        fetchURL(url + ([...params].length > 0 ? '&' : '') + params.toString());
    }

    function pagination(e) {
            pageCall(e.target.innerText);
        
        let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dots')[0];
            let numb1 = document.getElementById('numb1');
            if (parseInt(e.target.innerText) >= 2) {
                numb1.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', dots);
            }       
      }

}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    --primary-color: #39445a;
    --secondary-color: rgb(34, 24, 24);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.header{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 30px 0px 20px;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 6px rgb(20, 19, 19);
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
.header a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.app{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    width:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

.app h1{
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color:#39445a;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.movie_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.movie{
    cursor:pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #282c34;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
}

.movie:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.movie .movie_title{
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: center;
}

.movie:hover .movie_title{
    color:#282c34;
}

.movie .rate{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    min-width: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: transform 225ms cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.spans{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.movie .movie_date{
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:rgb(189, 179, 179);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-align: right;
}

.popup{
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    width:80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    height:80%;
    max-height: 90%;
}

.close_popup{
    align-self: flex-start;
    margin:20px;
}

.close_popup i{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size:1.7rem;
}

.close_popup i:hover{
    color: #b5b8c0;
}

.popup.active{
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

#overlay{
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.popup_right{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:first baseline;
    align-items: center;
    width:60%;
    height:80%;
}

#popup_title{
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:100;
}

#popup_tagline{
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:200;
}

.description{
    display: flex;
    height: 40%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:100;
}

.text{
    margin:5px;
}

.popup_left{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin:30px;
    height:100%;
    width:400px;
}

.popup_left img{
    width:400px;
    height:550px;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.pagination{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.pagination ul{
    width: 30%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.pagination ul li{
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.pagination ul li.numb{
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
}

.pagination ul li.btn{
    background: turquoise;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.pagination ul li.btn.disabled{
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.pagination ul li.prev{
    border-radius: 25px 5px 5px 25px;
}

.pagination ul li.next{
    border-radius: 5px 25px 25px 5px;  
}

.pagination ul li.active,
.pagination ul li:hover,
.pagination ul li:active{
    background: #4d5f85;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.bottom_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height:70px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 70px;
    background-color: #2d313a;
}

.btn{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.btn a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.icon{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon_text{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.genres{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin:10px;
}

.genres .genre{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 3px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px 15px;
    font-size: 0.850rem;
    margin:2px;
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.genres .genre.active{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
}

.genres span.close{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 2px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: 0.850rem;
    color: #3f51b5;
    background-color: rgba(172, 157, 157, 0.7);
}

.search-container{
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.search-container input[type=text]{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px;
    width:700px;
    height:40px;
    border: 1px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
    color:#fff;
}


.search-container button{
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search_options{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 23%;
}

.option{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.75;
    white-space: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:10px 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #fff, rgb(116, 113, 113));
}

.option > span{
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f84da73aa8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Movie Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="header">
        movie search
    </div>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>trending today</h1>
        <div class="movie_container" id="movie_container">
            <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <div class="popup_left">
                    <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="popup_right">
                        <span class="text" id="popup_title">Movie Title</span>
                        <span class="text" id="popup_tagline">Tagline</span>
                        <div class="description">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <span data-close-button="close_button" class="close_popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
            <div class="movie" data-modal-target=".popup">
                <span class="rate">fuck</span>
                <img src="img/dark_knight.jpg">
                <span class="movie_title">the dark knight</span>
                <div class="spans">
                    <span class="movie_date">USA</span>
                     <span class="movie_date" style="text-align: left;">I'm Batman</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul id="pag">
                <li class="btn prev" id="prev"><span><i class="fas fa-angle-left">Prev</i></span></li>
                <li class="numb active" id="numb1"><span>1</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>2</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>3</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>4</span></li>
                <li class="numb" id="numb5"><span>5</span></li>
                <li class="dots"><span>...</span></li>
                <li class="numb"><span>10</span></li>
                <li class="btn next" id="next"><span>Next<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_menu">
            <div class="btn">            
                <span class="material-icons icon">whatshot</span>
                <span class="icon_text">trending</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <span class="material-icons icon">movie</span>
                <span class="icon_text"><a href="movies.html">movies</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <span class="material-icons icon">desktop_windows</span>
                <span class="icon_text">TV series</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">
                <span class="material-icons icon">search</span>
                <span class="icon_text"><a href="search.html">search</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target')` is this really your selector? You forgot the closing `]`. Does the browser console output anything?

Comment: you're right, i forgot to close it but after doing it things didn't really change and console doesn't output anything

Comment: Oh okay. Would you mind making this a runnable example? The `[<>]` button lets you enter the code to run inside StackOverflow so we can debug it directly. Maybe you have added click handlers before the elements are added?

Comment: i could add it but for some reason it doesn't display API in stackoverflow, but i'll try to add a snippet

Comment: I found that sometimes I create a snippet and solve the problem along the way because I'm thinking of every part clearly to create the snippet. I'll maybe check again later when you update.

Comment: hey! i added a snippet and it seems to display api properly, so maybe you could understand the code more clearly

Comment: I may have an idea, yes. In `popUp();` you have `movie.forEach(el =>{ ...`, but `movie` is not all the HTML elements, it is just one. Try `console.log(movie);` before the forEach and you can see. It has to be all the HTML elements. Probably not the solution but maybe a symptom.

Comment: In your `window.onload` function you create your variables, like `const movie = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');`. But you add elements later. If you use `let` instead of `const` the selected elements might update in the variable, worth a try. Otherwise add click handlers *after* you added the elements to the page.

Comment: hey, i've added `let movie` inside of popup function and also called console.log(movie) as you can see in edited snipped, but it says that movie length is 1, tho there must be many elements. and it doesn't add popup element to movie_container for some reason

Comment: Okay, so you may want to create all the elements first, then loop over the `data-model-target` divs at the end to add the click handler. You can always `console.log` calls to find which code is not executed.